# enum array index in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing

I am working with RGB colour data in a C# (WPF) app, and find myself with a lot of cut and pasted code along the lines of

```
totals.red += currentPixel.red;
totals.green += currentPixel.green;
totals.blue += currentPixel.blue;
```

I'd like to reduce this copy-pasting and vulnerability to copy-paste errors. I could use arrays of size 3 around the place, but accessing those by number reduces readability.

I'd like to write something like this:

```
for (col = all colours) {
  totals[col] += currentPixel[col];
}
```

I'd know how to go about this in C, but am unfamiliar with C#. Something with enums?

Edit: Made the example make more sense.

Comment: What are `red`, `thing`, and `otherthing`?

Comment: Are `red`, `green` and `blue` all members of a type, or are just just hanging around on their own?  If the former, which type, if the latter, why aren't they grouped together?

Comment: As others have commented, it's not clear what you are trying to achieve. I'd rather you write it out in C and have people help you translate the same to C#.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use enums for this, you can do it this way:

```
enum Color { red, green, blue };

{
    foreach (int colorValue in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Color)))
        thing[colorValue] = otherthing[colorValue] * 2;
}
```

This would also allow you to grab an individual color by name in other code:

```
var color = thing[Color.red];
```

Comment: This is the most promising so far, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that red, green and blue are of type Color

You can setup a List of colours

```
List<Color> colors = new List<Color>();
```

Add items to it:

```
colors.Add(green);
colors.Add(blue);
colors.Add(red);
```

Then itterate:

```
foreach (Color color in colors)
{
    color.thing = color.otherThing * 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enums won't help here. But you can define your own type as done in [Integer array or struct array - which is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441466/integer-array-or-struct-array-which-is-better), and overload the arithmetic operators as described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s(v=vs.80).aspx to allow multiplying to an int for example. E.g.

```
thing = otherthing * 2;
```